# How to get main thread and set its priority

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm creating app which runs parrarel some functions, at beggining of main method i have tried getting current thread and changing its priority. Im not sure about is Parrarel.For is creating new **Threads/Tasks**.

```
Parallel.For(0,50,(i) =>
{       
   Guesser guesser = new Guesser();
   guesser.startBruteForce();
});
```

It runs only 9 instaces of my class ( checked with console printing in contructor ), and the next objects are created after few seconds. I suppose that changing main thread priority (if it is a thread) to higher will prevent scheduler from taking resources to create new object.

Comment: Well, i do not really understand what you want do. Your explanation is not clear to me. So i will restrict myself to the title of your question: Check the documentation for the `System.Threading.Thread` type. It has properties/methods for both getting the current thread as well as changing the priority of a thread...

Comment: I'd like to get handle for the main thread at set it priority to higher.

Comment: As i said, check the documentation for `System.Threading.Thread`. You will do yourself no favor as a programmer if you are unwilling to read/browse/search/revisit documentation ;-)

Comment: So you are saying that `Parallel.For` is creating too many threads? What is your goal by limiting resources of other threads?

Comment: You are almost surely asking for `Thread.CurrentThread`.  Consider the ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism property, you can set it 1 lower then Environment.ProcessorCount so the main thread doesn't have to compete with the parallel threads.

Comment: As i understand it will just limit my threads count that my Parrarel.For can create. But i want to create all of them and scheduler wont let me  do that. Is there a way to set priority of parrarel threads to lower than main?

Comment: If you want to create 50 threads, create them manually. `Parallel.For` is meant to manage thread pool threads. The other issue you have is just because you have 50 threads, doesn't mean it will run 50 times faster. Often creating too many threads actually results in a decrease in performance because now you just have 4 cores (for example) that have to context switch between 50 threads. This is is processor starvation.

Comment: "_As i understand it will just limit my threads count that my Parrarel.For can create_". No. No. Just read the documentation for `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. It limits the amount of **CONCURRENT** tasks/threads. If you tell Parallel.Foreach to create 50 tasks, then it will create 50 tasks, irregardless of the value of `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. Think of the tasks you create as cars on a highway. `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` specifies how many lanes the highway has at most, it does NOT specify how many cars (tasks) can drive on the highway.

Comment: @elgonzo I got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TPL ( Task Parallel Library )** is a set of types and API that provide developers an easy way
to add parallelism and concurrency in their .NET applicaiton .

If you try to limit the number of created `Task`, that doesn't make sense because it's managed by `ThreadPool` it self .

You can check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool

I just add some code that you can test and i confirm that it works well (code below).

**Application Console :**

```
public readonly static object Locker = new object();

    private static int threadNumber;

    public static int ThreadNumber
    {
        get { return threadNumber; }
        set
        {
            lock(Locker)
            threadNumber = value;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Parallel.For(0, 50, (i) =>
        {
                Guesser guesser = new Guesser();
                guesser.StartBruteForce(ref threadNumber);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

**Class Guesser :**

```
internal class Guesser
{
    internal void StartBruteForce(ref int threadNumber)
    {
        threadNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is internal for? it is equal to private?

Comment: It's an access specifiers that hides members and variable  from others namespace .

Comment: I have last question. When I create Threads with normal for `for(int i =0;i<8;i++)
            {
                Guesser guesser = new Guesser();
                Thread thread = new Thread(guesser.startBruteForce);
                thread.Start();
            }`it seems to work faster than version from the post. startBruteForce is calling  a recursive function that check if generated key==password. I writed key on console  what showed me that normal for is creating more permutated keys. What can cause it ?//i dont know how to format code here